# Basic jQuery Slider - select a startslide

Tags: jquery, slider

i try to define a startslide for this slider:
http://www.basic-slider.com/

you can set a random startslide but you cant say that you want, that the slider starts/loads directly at slide 3, 4 or 5 etc..

option for randomslide:
"randomstart : true"

```
var conf_random = function() {

        var rand            = Math.floor(Math.random() * state.slidecount) + 1;
        state.currentslide  = rand;
        state.currentindex  = rand-1;

    };
```

does anyone have a solution for me to set a startslide?

Comment: How about this trick: Trigger click at marker of slide that you want on page ready?

Comment: hey teddy thats a good solution. never thought of that. thank you!! :)